# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'SBHMasterPage'?

Tags: asp.net

> I tried for this how to fix its?

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'SBHMasterPage'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'SBHMasterPage'.

Source Error:

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'SBHMasterPage'.]
   SBHSetTitle.Page_Load(Object o, EventArgs e) +65
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Comment: The offending code appears to be on line 65

Answer (score 3):

Try to set

```
<compilation debug="true" batch="false" >
```

in your web.config. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have no idea how and why it worked but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a randomly occurring bug that is difficult to pinpoint, but it does have an unpublished hotfix that you need to call to get.

See [Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.masterpage_master' to type 'ASP.masterpage_master'.](https://love2dev.com/blog/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-aspmasterpage_master-to-type-aspmasterpage_master/)

Sadly, the link is no longer valid. Typical Microsoft.

There is a page on ASP.net with good discussion (all over 10 years old) and lots of solutions to try:

https://forums.asp.net/t/954194.aspx

The most promising solution seems to be adding **batch="false"** to your `web.config` file, like this:

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false"/>
```

Doing this will slow down Visual Studio compile times.

I have submitted a similar question on ASP.NET Forums that has received some attention, but there are no solutions.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2172428.aspx